# Django - Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `address` on serializer `RegistrationSerializer`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests, django-serializer

I 'm trying to build a view to create a new user.

In this view I call a serializer which must use 2 different tables

Here is the request :

```
{
    "email": "email@example.com",
    "name": "name",
    "surname": "surname",
    "phone": "0601234567",
    "password": "azerty",
    "address": {
        "osm": "N65719518",
        "lat": 18.072,
        "lon": 36.087,
        "street": "Name of the street",
        "postalCode": 123456,
        "city": "name of the city"
    }
}
```

I would like to separate the "address" field from my query which corresponds to another table.
For this I use the pop method in my serializer
Here is my serializer :

**serializers.py**

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'

class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Create an account"""
    address = AddressSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ['joined', 'lastLogin', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_admin', 'is_active']
        extra_kwargs = {
            # For security to hide the password (we can't read it)
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }

    def save(self):
        # Pop the address of the user
        address = self.validated_data.pop("address")
        user = User.objects.create(**self.validated_data)
        user.set_password(self.validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        Address.objects.create(user=user, **address)
        token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
        confirmation(user, token.key)
        return user
```

Here is the view in which I call my serializer :

**views.py**

```
class HandleUsers(HandleUsersView):
    def post(self, request):
        """For everyone"""
        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            token = Token.objects.get(user=user).key
            return Response({**{'id': user.id},**serializer.data, **{'token': token}})
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Here is the full error that I get :

> "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `address` on serializer `RegistrationSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `OrderedDict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'address'."

Thank you by advance for your help

Comment: From which line exactly does this error traceback come from?

Comment: It is not specified in the console but I think the error came when i call the AddressSerializer to define the field address in my RegistrationSerializer class

Comment: Don´t do a creation at `save()`. It belongs to `create()`. If you handle a `put`, it always creates object in your case. It won´t update your `User` or `Address`. Instead of using a `AddressSerializer()` you can add `depth=1`

Answer (score 1):

For a better explanation to my comment.
`save()` calls either `create()` or `update()`. Indeed you can override `save()` but I don´t recommend it.

If you do

```
serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
 if serializer.is_valid():
    user = serializer.save()
```

your `save()` calls `create()` because a value was assigned to data.

If you do

```
instance = User.objects.get(....)
serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data, instance=instance)
 if serializer.is_valid():
    user = serializer.save()
```

your `save()` calls `update()` because values were assigned to `data` and `instance`.

If you want you can pass additional attributes to `save()`

[drf saving instance](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)